# Regex to capture a number from an URL

Tags: regex

can someone please show me to how to capture the number (23456) in this URL using Regex.

http://www.examplweb.com/data/23456/my-test-45-check-out.aspx

Comment: This question needs more detail to be answerable. Are you asking "how do I write a regex that matches 23456?" Or do you want to know how to capture whatever is in that section of some URLs? Please give some examples of test cases and what they should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b\d+(?=\/[^\/]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/26